# How to restore pam configuration?

Tags: ubuntu-12.04, pam

I did some modifications in `/etc/pam.d/common-auth`, `/etc/pam.d/common-account`, `/etc/pam.d/common-password`, `/etc/pam.d/common-session` files. Is there any way to restore default pam configuration?

I am using ubuntu 12.04

Comment: As advised by most guides on pam changes, you restore them from the backups you made (or copy them from another machine where you hadn't altered them)

Answer (score 10):

I believe the `pam-auth-update` command resets to defaults.

Comment: I know this is old but it helped solve my own issue of trying to reset and remove a machine from my LDAP configuration.  Using "pam-auth-update --force" was exactly the trick to reset to base install settings.